# How to keep the text always in the center of the line on the LCD?

Tags: 8051, keil

How to keep the text always in the center while putting other words on LCD like in MS Word using assembly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a 16*2 Lcd, there are address associated with each character that you display on lcd which is given in the datasheet.
Usually, to set the cursor on start position of line 1, the command is 0x80 and it goes on, for 0x81 will move the cursor to next position on line 1 and last position on line one will have address 0x8F.
Similarly for second line, the address will range from 0xC0 to 0XCF.

This might help you in aligning the text in center of LCD.

Answer (score 0):

I created a formula for that, here is a void version:

```
void printCenter(int locationY,String text) {
    int centerPoint = (240 - text.length()) / 2;
    lcd.setCursor(centerPoint,locationY);
    lcd.print(text);
}
```

This void function gets the screen width (for example, 240px) and string's length, and the screens are write every letter in 1px, so it subtracts the string's length from screen width. Now we have the empty space of the line. It divides "240 - text.lenght()" to 2 so we can have the first half of the empty space. My function uses a "setCursor" and "print" to display it centered.

**Note**: I tested it in 16x2 and 240x240 pixels displays, it works very well, but you may need to calculate via font-size if it is defined.